# How to output MemoryDB cluster endpoint/port/credentials in CDK script

Tags: aws-cdk

I have a memory DB cluster defined like this:

```
const memorydb_cluster = new CfnCluster(this, 'memorydb', {
      aclName: 'open-access',
      clusterName: 'redis-cluster',
      nodeType: 'db.t4g.medium',
      autoMinorVersionUpgrade: false,
      engineVersion: '7.0',
      numShards: 1,
      numReplicasPerShard: 0,
      securityGroupIds: [ecSecurityGroup.securityGroupId],
      subnetGroupName: groupName,
      tlsEnabled: true,
    });
```

I would like to use the endpoint/port/credentials as environment variables in other constructs that rely on this. So far I have tried:

```
const redisUrl = memorydb_cluster.attrClusterEndpointAddress;
const redisPort = memorydb_cluster.attrClusterEndpointPort;
```

and

```
const redisUrl = cdk.Stack.of(memorydb_cluster).resolve(memorydb_cluster.attrClusterEndpointAddress);
const redisPort = cdk.Stack.of(memorydb_cluster).resolve(memorydb_cluster.attrClusterEndpointPort);
```

But it only outputs -1.8881545897089002e+289 ${Token[TOKEN.694]} for port and endpoint respectively. How do I get these values within the CDK script?

Comment: Pass them around as normal, they are not known during CDK code execution and will be resolved to their actual values during deployment.